# unable to create new object and use export class in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is class UserDetails::

```
export class UserDetails {
name:string;
phoneNumber:string;
email:string;
password: string;
 }
```

below is service in which userDetails is used::

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { userDetails } from './_models/index';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
private loginUserUrl="http://localhost:8082/TodoApp/login";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
//let user = new UserDetails();
}

login(email: string, password: string) {
    console.log("in login service");

    let user = new User();
   user.email=email;
    user.password=password;

    return this.http.post(this.loginUserUrl,user);
    .map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the 
             response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        });
      }

}
```

error::::eferenceError: UserDetails is not defined
    at AuthenticationService.login (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts:25)

Comment: what is `let user = new User();` you have no `User` class?

Comment: i tried with let user =new userDetails() then too getting error

Comment: @RaginiPatil what error ?

Comment: @imran ERROR ReferenceError: UserDetails is not defined
    at AuthenticationService.login (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/_services/authentication.service.ts:25) as given above

Comment: Yeah, it more like a comment, sorry for not clarifying. So which line is line 25 which shown in error? Since in your code I see no use of (uncommented) `UserDetails` at all, so I don't understand error really :) (Also you have imported it as `userDetails`)

Comment: I think your path is incorrect . Please correct your path and follow inject your model in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import { UserDetails as User } from './_models/index';
//...
let user = new User();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong , you are doing **`userDetails`** instead of **`UserDetails`** ,change it as

```
import { UserDetails } from './_models/index';
```

and the object should be created as,

```
 let user = new UserDetails();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise a model variable in your constructor for `UserDetails` like this

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private user:UserDetails) {

}
```

This will create a object `user` of type `UserDetails` which you can use like you have used `http`. Like this,

```
this.user.email=email;
this.user.password=password;
```

Comment: Replace `userDetail` with `UserDetail` having uppercase `U` in your import